# turn time series data into nested data frame where groups are increasing time periods (w/dplyr & tidyr)

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr, purrr

I have a dataset with daily counts per year spanning several decades, and I'd like to run a function on different subsets of that data based on an increasing timespan. For example, I'd like to run the function on the first decade of data (1995-2005), then on the first decade + 1 (1995-2006), first decade + 2 (1995-2007), and so on until the end of the time series. This is what I had in mind:

```
dat <- tibble(
  year = rep(1995:2014, each = 30),
  count = rpois(600, 5)
)
dat

# A tibble: 600 x 2
    year count
   <int> <int>
 1  1995     8
 2  1995     3
 3  1995     9
 4  1995     2
 5  1995     8
 6  1995     7
 7  1995     3
 8  1995     6
 9  1995     1
10  1995     7
# … with 590 more rows
```

with the final product looking like this:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 2
  time_span data              
  <chr>     <list>            
1 1995-2004 <tibble [300 × 1]>
2 1995-2005 <tibble [330 × 1]>
3 1995-2006 <tibble [360 × 1]>
...
```

I would then apply my function to the nested data frame:

```
dat_nested %>%
  mutate(result = map(data, my_function))
```

I'm struggling to think of a way to create these subsets with dplyr...any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: I would probably replicate your original dataset 3 times, create a different subset in each dataframe, remove any other data from the datasets and then bind them back together? Since you have the same data present in multiple subsets I can't see a simpler way to do it without replicating the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way using `map` :

```
library(dplyr)

n <- min(dat$year)
purrr::map_df((n+10):max(dat$year), 
    ~dat %>% 
      filter(between(year, n, .x)) %>%
      summarise(year = paste(min(year), max(year), sep = '-'), 
                data = list(count)))
                #If you want dataframe
                #data = list(data.frame(count = count))))

#     year      data       
#   <chr>     <list>     
# 1 1995-2005 <int [330]>
# 2 1995-2006 <int [360]>
# 3 1995-2007 <int [390]>
# 4 1995-2008 <int [420]>
# 5 1995-2009 <int [450]>
# 6 1995-2010 <int [480]>
# 7 1995-2011 <int [510]>
# 8 1995-2012 <int [540]>
# 9 1995-2013 <int [570]>
#10 1995-2014 <int [600]>
```

Answer (score 1):

The result could be directly calculated from the original data frame without the need of an intermediate nested data frame and we show that below; however, if you do want to create a nested data frame anyways then use the same code but use it with

```
my_function <- base::list
```

to nest the two columns or with

```
my_function <- function(x) list(x["count"])
```

to just nest the `count` column.  The solution only uses dplyr.  It does not use tidyr or purrr.

```
library(dplyr)

my_function <- function(x) sum(x$count)  # test function

dat %>%
  group_by(year) %>%
  summarize(result = my_function(.[.$year <= first(year), ]), .groups = "drop") %>%
  mutate(year = paste(first(year), year, sep = "-")) %>%
  tail(-9)
```

giving:

```
# A tibble: 11 x 2
   year      result
   <chr>      <int>
 1 1995-2004   1502
 2 1995-2005   1647
 3 1995-2006   1810
 4 1995-2007   1957
 5 1995-2008   2106
 6 1995-2009   2258
 7 1995-2010   2398
 8 1995-2011   2547
 9 1995-2012   2697
10 1995-2013   2855
11 1995-2014   3016
```

With `my_function <- function(x) list(x["count"])` the output looks like this:

```
# A tibble: 11 x 2
   year      result            
   <chr>     <list>            
 1 1995-2004 <tibble [300 x 1]>
 2 1995-2005 <tibble [330 x 1]>
 3 1995-2006 <tibble [360 x 1]>
 4 1995-2007 <tibble [390 x 1]>
 5 1995-2008 <tibble [420 x 1]>
 6 1995-2009 <tibble [450 x 1]>
 7 1995-2010 <tibble [480 x 1]>
 8 1995-2011 <tibble [510 x 1]>
 9 1995-2012 <tibble [540 x 1]>
10 1995-2013 <tibble [570 x 1]>
11 1995-2014 <tibble [600 x 1]>
```

### Note

The test input `dat` in reproducible form is:

```
set.seed(123)
dat <- data.frame(year = rep(1995:2014, each = 30), count = rpois(600, 5))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my attempt to create a nested data with time-series data on a rolling window basis. (note: `rlang` usage of `var=enquo(str_varname)` with `!!var` may change in the future versions.)

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

create_rolling_yr_data <- function(df, year='year', rolling=9, 
                                   var_list=c('count'), newvar='rolling') {
  year <- enquo(year)
  var_list <- enquos(var_list)

  df <- df %>% dplyr::select(!!year, !!!var_list)
  df_nest <- df %>% group_by(year) %>% nest()
  print(df_nest)
  list_data <- list()
  yrs <- unique(df[[ensym(year)]]) 
  yr_end <- max(yrs) - rolling
  for (i in seq_along(yrs)) {
    yr <- yrs[i]
    if (yr <= yr_end) {
      list_data[[i]] <- df %>% filter(year >= yr, year <= (yr+rolling))
    } else {
      list_data[[i]] <- list()
    }
  }
  df_nest[[newvar]] <- list_data
  return(df_nest %>% filter(year <= yr_end))
}

create_rolling_yr_data(dat, year='year', rolling=9, 
                       var_list=c('count'), newvar='rolling')
```